# How to implement put request correctly in spring boot?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest

I have basic question about rest controller in spring boot. Example to explain the
question:
I have the following code from angular:

```
updateMyEntity(myEntityTemp: MyEntity) {
    let imyEntityObj = {
      myEntity: myEntityTemp
    };    
    return this.http.put(`${AppComponent.ENTITY_API}/Update`, JSON.stringify(imyEntityObj), httpOptions);
```

My question is about the syntax of the rest controller, here it is:

```
 @PutMapping("/Update")     
    public MyEntity updateMyEntity(@RequestBody MyEntity myEntity) {    
     }
```

Is the @RequestBody annotation required? I mean, it won't work without it?

Comment: how are you going to Put something without a body?

Comment: Well, In other framework the rest method in java was without any annotation

Comment: I'm adding @RequestBody to all save methods in the microservices and hope for good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using @Controller and you have returne any String (not view) then you have add @RequestBody.

If you are using @RestController then no need.

Comment: Well all my controllers are annotated with RestController and still I added @Requestbody to all save and update method. that will work or should I remove them

Comment: No need @RequestBody

Comment: @RequestController has itself

Comment: I'll removed the @RequestBody annotation as I don't want redundant

Answer (score 0):

@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody

But @RequestBody is still needed if you have some data in the request body to be processed. If path variable is enough for your operation  then we don’t need @RequestBody.

Per your posted code, you want to process myEntity then you need it.