# How Creat In java Spring Boot Put Request with Object JSON parameters

Tags: java, angular

I have error 500  on my restweb services.

So I have a simple rest controller api in backend in java spring boot and make it Angular with a httpclient service

I know the @RequestBody annotation is not useful.

it try to add "parameters=" on the body resquest (same)

I think my problem comes from my Java part.

```
OPTIONS "/api/adress/sav", parameters={}
Mapped to saveAdress(Adress)
Completed 200 OK
PUT "/api/adress/sav", parameters={}
Mapped to com.gcssara.hexa.application.AdressEndPoint#saveAdress(Adress)
Failed to complete request: java.lang.NullPointerException
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
"ERROR" dispatch for PUT "/error", parameters={}
Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
Writing [{timestamp=Tue Aug 30 14:41:23 CEST 2022, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, path=/api/adressm (truncated)...]
Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/adress")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class AdressEndPoint {

    @PutMapping(path ="/sav")
    public Adress saveAdress( Adresse adress) {
return adressService.saveAdress(adress);
    }

}
```

```js
createUpdate(adress:Adress, ) {
      return this._httpClient.put<Adress>(this.requestUrlBase +"/api/adress/sav",JSON.stringify(adress), {} );
    }
```

```
URL de la demande: http://localhost:8080/api/adress/sav
Request method: PUT
Status code: 415
Remote address: [::1]:8080
Access point policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept: application/json, application/*+json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2022 13:17:57 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 194
Content-Type: text/plain
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Microsoft Edge";v="104"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.102 Safari/537.36 Edg/104.0.1293.70
```

Comment: Have you inspected your spring security configuration?

Comment: why is @RequestBody not usefull? you'll need it to map the request body

Comment: `@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody`
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68356191/how-to-implement-put-request-correctly-in-spring-boot

Comment: And if i add `@RequestBody` at my parameter i have  "Completed 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE"

Comment: then set content-type header on the request to application/json

Comment: content type is already application/json

Comment: if i set content-type i have 500 nullPointErexception